# How to use boost::variant correctly?

Tags: c++

I'm intending to use 3D vector with heterogeneous data. I found a solution of using `boost::variant` or `boost.any`. However, I could not find any simple tutorial on that. What is the library I should include? anyone can give me simple tutorial or example please?

Comment: [`boost::any example`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any/s02.html) and [`boost::variant tutorial`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely a relatively simple tutorial/reference at the boost website (
[boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) and [boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html)).

As for the libraries that you should include: that would be boost of course. Specifically, the header files you need are `boost/variant.hpp` and `boost/any.hpp`. Both libraries are header only libraries. This means that you should just install boost (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 5):

Boost.Variant and Boost.Any have different usecases.

Boost.Variant is about sum types: your type represent a union of different types, one among many:

- Requires: knowing the list of all possible types
- Advantages: you can query it to know which type is active at the moment and all operations are checked at compile time.

Boost.Any, on the other hand, is type erasure at its finest. It can hold any type, even built-in types like `int`.

- Requires: knowing the type held within to do any operation on it
- Advantages: the code that just pass `boost::any` around can be oblivious to the types it could hold